# Making multiple rectangles in SVG by D3 error

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, charts, graphics

In example I am making 3 rectangles based on custom data. I should have got my 3 rectangles but still getting error. Can someone help out?

**SNIPPET:**

```
<html>

<head>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.3.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<script> 

$(document).ready(function(){

    //our basic data 
     var rectData = [
        { "x": 30, "y": 30, "width": 20, "height" : 10 },
        { "x": 70, "y": 70, "width": 20, "height" : 20},
        { "x": 110, "y": 100, "width": 20, "height" : 30}
     ];

    //selection of svg 
    var mySVG = d3.select("svg");

    //create rectangle skeleton 
    var rect = mySVG.selectAll("rect")
            .data(rectData)
            .enter()
            .append("rect");

    //Draw the Rectangle
    mySVG.append("rect")
        .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("width", function (d) { return d.width; })
        .style("height", function(d) { return d.height; });

});

</script>   
</head>
<body>
    <svg width="500px" height="500px"></svg>
</body>
</html>
```

**Error:**

```
 .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x; })
```

[image]

Please, help out in knowing what is the errror in the program and help me create the three rectangles based on the custom data in array. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use your recently created `rect` variable, which contains your "enter" selection:

```
rect.attr("x", function (d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("width", function (d) { return d.width; })
    .style("height", function(d) { return d.height; });
```

You're getting this error because you're using `mySVG` to set the attributes, which is just an SVG selection and has no bound data (hence, no `d.x`, `d.y` etc...).

Answer (score 1):

Just combine the following two scripts into one.

```
//create rectangle skeleton 
var rect = mySVG.selectAll("rect")
        .data(rectData)
        .enter()
        .append("rect");

//Draw the Rectangle
mySVG.append("rect")
    .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("width", function (d) { return d.width; })
    .style("height", function(d) { return d.height; });
```

changes to

```
//create rectangle skeletons and draw the rectangles
var rect = mySVG.selectAll("rect")
        .data(rectData)
        .enter()
        .append("rect");
        .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("width", function (d) { return d.width; })
        .style("height", function(d) { return d.height; });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mwf2d1fd/ A JS fiddle